# Node.js - Remove null elements from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to remove null/empty elements from JSON objects, similar to the functionality of the python webutil/util.py -> trim_nulls method. Is there something built in to Node that I can use, or is it a custom method.

Example:

```
var foo = {a: "val", b: null, c: { a: "child val", b: "sample", c: {}, d: 123 } };
```

Expected Result:

```
foo = {a: "val", c: { a: "child val", b: "sample", d: 123 } };
```

Comment: You could loop through all the elements and unset them if they are null.

Comment: Look at this answer.
There is a useful script for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/525181/1586177

Comment: possible duplicate of [null / empty json how to check for it and not output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524993/null-empty-json-how-to-check-for-it-and-not-output)

Comment: Do you really mean JSON objects, or do you mean JavaScript objects? Your title and description say JSON, but your example code is JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why people were upvoting my original answer, it was wrong (guess they just looked too quick, like I did). Anyway, I'm not familiar with node, so I don't know if it includes something for this, but I think you'd need something like this to do it in straight JS:

```
var remove_empty = function ( target ) {

  Object.keys( target ).map( function ( key ) {

    if ( target[ key ] instanceof Object ) {

      if ( ! Object.keys( target[ key ] ).length && typeof target[ key ].getMonth !== 'function') {

        delete target[ key ];

      }

      else {

        remove_empty( target[ key ] );

      }

    }

    else if ( target[ key ] === null ) {

      delete target[ key ];

    }

  } );


  return target;

};

remove_empty( foo );
```

I didn't try this with an array in `foo` -- might need extra logic to handle that differently.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
let fooText = JSON.stringify(foo);
    
let filteredFoo = JSON.parse(objectLogText, (key, value) => {if(value !== null) return value});
```

[JSON.parse() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this :

```
Object.keys(foo).forEach(index => (!foo[index] && foo[index] !== undefined) && delete foo[index]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the help.. I've pieced the following code using the feedback in all of the comments which works with foo.

```
function trim_nulls(data) {
  var y;
  for (var x in data) {
    y = data[x];
    if (y==="null" || y===null || y==="" || typeof y === "undefined" || (y instanceof Object && Object.keys(y).length == 0)) {
      delete data[x];
    }
    if (y instanceof Object) y = trim_nulls(y);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: That'll remove `0`'s won't it? Is that intentional?

Comment: yeah good point, I'll change the "if (!y" statement to suit. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be the most elegant way. Also I believe JS-engines are heavily optimized for it.

> use built in `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])` functionality. Docs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Example is in context of retrieving some data from an external API, defining some model accordingly, get the result and chop of everything that couldn't be defined or unwanted:

```
function chop (obj, cb) {
  const valueBlacklist = [''];
  const keyBlacklist = ['_id', '__v'];

  let res = JSON.stringify(obj, function chopChop (key, value) {
    if (keyBlacklist.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      return undefined;
    }

    // this here checks against the array, but also for undefined
    // and empty array as value
    if (value === null || value === undefined || value.length < 0 || valueBlacklist.indexOf(value) > -1) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return value;
 })
 return cb(res);
}
```

In your implementation.

```
// within your route handling you get the raw object `result`
chop(user, function (result) {
   var body = result || '';
   res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });
   res.write(body);
   // bang! finsihed.
   return res.end();
});

// end of route handling
```

Comment: Nice very elegant, used stringify all the time, never thought of using it this way, nice,

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter with a `for` loop and output to a new clean object:

```
var cleanFoo = {};
for (var i in foo) {
  if (foo[i] !== null) {
    cleanFoo[i] = foo[i];
  }
}
```

If you need to process children objects too you'll need recursion.